# Failure building Android project with gradle error: "Illegal embedded sign character"

Tags: android, gradle, nexus

Can't make Android project build with gradle assemble task. I'm getting

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProjectTitle'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download javax.activation.jar (com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0)
      > Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'https://nexus.mycompanydomain.com/repository/jcenter-cache/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar'.
         > Illegal embedded sign character
```

We are using our own Nexus artifactory repository. It works fine for some colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, you need to clean `~/.gradle/caches/` folder.

Comment: note, that `~/.gradle` folder is hidden, so you might need to "show hidden files".

Comment: You can mark this as the answer I suppose. I had the same problem - cleaning the caches solved this indeed.